# Where is my .sh script syntax error(s)?

Tags: scripting, aix, variable

Trying to run a small simple script to pull the `java -version` information from an AIX system's several java64 folders piped into an output/log file using the system's hostname but can't seem to get it to work.

```
#
# Start Script
#

date > ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
echo "------ Java v1.4 Information ------" >> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
/usr/java14_64/bin/java -version 2 >> ./${$HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
echo "------ Java v5 Information ------" >> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
/usr/java5_64/bin/java -version 2 >> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
echo "------ Java v6 Information ------" >> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
/usr/java6_64/bin/java -version 2 >> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
echo "------ Java v7 Information ------" >> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
/usr/java7_64/bin/java -version 2 >> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt

#
# End Script
# *
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! Please [edit] your question to add more detail regarding the errors you're seeing and what you've tried to fix them.

Comment: If it's a `sh` script you ought to put `#!/bin/sh` as the first line.

Answer (score 3):

No space bewtween `2 >>`

```
java -version 2>> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
```

OR

```
java -version 2>> ./`hostname`_GetJava.txt
```

Comment: When I run this script I get an output file called _GetJava.txt and the machine/hostname is not getting used for output file name.

Comment: #!/bin/sh
#

#
# Start Script
#

date > ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt
echo "------ Java v1.4 Information ------" >> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt


/usr/java14_64/bin/java -version 2>> ./${HOSTNAME}_GetJava.txt

#
# End Script
# *

Comment: what is `echo $HOSTNAME` and `hostname` output?

Comment: My goal (since there are multiple LPAR's which I need to track java versions on) is to run a single script to collect the following information: 1) hostname where the script pulled the info from with the 2) date info is pulled, 3) text lines within the output file indicating which java version i was pulling the version information from, and 4) the output file name generated using the hostname from the machine the script is run from.  Both echo $HOSTNAME and hostname produce the same result (a display of the machine's hostname.

Comment: How do you run the script? it seems like `HOSTNAME` variable is empty when script is run.

Comment: Bless you!  it was the characters in the script surrounding hostname - when I used ` instead of ' it werked!  Thank-you!

Comment: try `logfile="./$(hostname)_GetJava.txt"` and then redirect output with `2>> "$logfile"`.  recomputing the logfile filename every time is wasteful and prone to typos and other errors.  and don't use backticks, they're obsolete and deprecated - use `$( ... )` instead.